# Offset address of Binary files

Tags: offset, binaryfiles, atmel, mplab, atmelstudio

I am using MPLAB to program ATSAMD20E15A. Now I have boot.bin and program.bin binray files generated.

My question is: How do I find the offset address of both these binary images?

Thank you and excuse me If the question is very basic since I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

The data sheet (page 265) says "The bootloader resides in the main array starting at offset zero." and appears to initially contain a factory programmed boot loader.

The boot loader code ends with a jump to the start of the runtime code which the program entry address must match.